# Are VS 2013 Pro & Web Essentials 2013 Compatible?

Tags: typescript

Using VS 2013 Pro and Web Essentials 2013 for a TS project. When I open a TS file in the VS editor, VS shuts down with an uncaught NullReferenceException. With Web Essentials disabled, all is OK. What am I doing wrong? Have I made some bad IDE choices?

Edit: Win7 Pro (x64) SP1, VS 2013 v12.0.21005.1, TS v0.9.7.0. VS 2013, TS and Web Essentials 2013 all downloaded and installed after 2014-03-08. Updated VS to VS 2013 Update 1 v12.0.30110.0. Problem persists.

Comment: You haven't provided many details about the environment -- specific versions of VS and the extension, OS, etc. Do you have any Updates to VS applied (like VS Update 2 CTP2 for example)?

Comment: Please give more details. You might need to reinstall TypeScript after your VS 2013 installation.

I am currently using VS 2013 Pro with TypeScript 0.9.5 and Web Essentials 2013, everything works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Visual Studio 2013 and Web Essentials 2013 are compatible. I'm using VS2013 version 12.0.30110.00 Update 1, Web Essentials 1.9 (and some other extensions like CKSDEV) and TypeScript 0.9.7.0 without any problems.

If your problem persists then your environment probably got corrupted somehow. I had the same experiance a couple of weeks ago and after some uninstalling and reinstalling the problem persisted and the only way to get rid of it was creating a new Virtual Machine with a fresh install of Visual Studio 2013.